# Opening RocksDB in Java with existing checkpoint files

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, rocksdb, checkpointing

I have a streaming pipeline that uses rocksdbjni 6.15.2 to manage and checkpoint state. I'm trying to use this same library in a separate offline Scala process to read the checkpoint files, and do some further processing.

To test, I copied one of the checkpoint state folders to a local folder:

```
ls /mnt/tmp/rocksdb/

010959.sst
CURRENT
MANIFEST-010701
OPTIONS-010704
```

and then ran this simple Scala program:

```
import org.rocksdb.{Options, RocksDB}

val dbPath = "/mnt/tmp/rocksdb"
val options = new Options().setCreateIfMissing(false)

RocksDB.loadLibrary()
val db: RocksDB = RocksDB.open(options, dbPath)
```

and run into this exception: `org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Corruption: IO error: No such file or directoryWhile open a file for random read: /mnt/tmp/rocksdb/010958.ldb: No such file or directory`

Has anyone run into this Exception before? Why is RocksDB looking for a `.ldb` file here?

Comment: Looking briefly at how Flink opens RocksDB, it appears to set createIfMissing to true; perhaps that's worth a try. FWIW, Flink also uses a different version of open, where it supplies columnFamilyDescriptors and columnFamilyHandles.

Comment: looking for a `.ldb` is fallback when `.sst` file not found, so this exception say that some sst file is missing